# Apache Cassandra reading data gives ReadFailureException

Tags: java, cassandra

I am writing a Java client which tests the reading of data of size of a million rows. I am filtering the data from the key in the map of a column. The code is creating and inserting the data properly but it is unable to read the data. My code is:

```
public class MillionMapTest {
    private Cluster cluster;
    private Session session;

    public void connect(String node) {
        cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(node).build();
        session = cluster.connect();
    }

    public void createSchema() {
        session.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE xx WITH replication " +
                "= {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':3};");
        session.execute(
                "CREATE TABLE xx.events (" +
                        "log_time_local timeuuid," +
                        "username text," +
                        "log_type text," +
                        "log_time timestamp," +
                        "device_category text," +
                        "log text," +
                        "priority INT," +
                        "client_ip text," +
                        "backend_app text," +
                        "location_details map<text, text>," +
                        "device_details map<text, text>," +
                        "extra_info Blob," +
                        "PRIMARY KEY (log_time_local, username, log_type)" +
                ");");
        session.execute("CREATE INDEX devicekeys ON xx.events(KEYS(device_details));");
    }

    public void loadData() {
        PreparedStatement statement = session.prepare(
                "INSERT INTO xx.events VALUES (now(), ?, ?, toTimestamp(now()), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
        BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(statement);
        for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
            Map<String, String> tags = new HashMap<>();
            tags.put("os", "ios");
            tags.put("category", "tab");
            tags.put("dev_num", "12ABF847CA");
            if (i % 100 == 0) tags.put("category", "mobile");
            session.execute(boundStatement.bind("name_"+i,"type_"+i, "cat_"+i, "log_"+i, i, "ip_"+i, "app_"+i, null, tags, null));
        }
    }

    public void querySchema() {
        ResultSet results = session.execute("SELECT * FROM xx.events WHERE device_details['category'] = 'mobile' ALLOW FILTERING;");    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MillionMapTest client = new MillionMapTest();
        client.connect("localhost");
        client.createSchema();
        client.loadData();
        client.querySchema();
        session.close();
        cluster.close();
    }
}
```

The error is `com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException: Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)`.

The query is running properly when running through `cqlsh` and this code worked with a few data. But it is not working with a million. What is causing this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Were you able to run this query from cqlsh?

Comment: @Rocherlee Yes, it works from cqlsh on the Cassandra server.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be the 'secondary index'. They are not the most performant thing in C* and comes with their own caveats. There are some good documentation about issues with secondary index in C* e.g. this [link](https://pantheon.io/blog/cassandra-scale-problem-secondary-indexes). You have got secondary index and that too on a map data type. This will be slow. The fact that you get ReadFailureException instead of ReadTimeout may be something to do with index not being up to date when you get to query it (I am not too sure about it but refer this [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8505) which is a case where ReadFailureException can be thrown).

I think you should look at remodelling your schema or denormalizing your table and may be have a way of doing key lookups rather than relying on secondary index.

Comment: I tried running this query on cqlsh and it worked. I tried it with little data and it worked.

The issue in the second link was solved in version 3.1. I am using version 3.7